# Shell Script - Using the diff command

Tags: shell, scripting, command, diff

This doesn't seem to be working correctly.
$4 is a C file. $in is the input file. $5 is a newly created output file, after $in inputs to $4 (I'm not really sure about this one.)

$out is an output that I created before running the script.

After, I'm comparing $5 and $out to see if they are equal.

I'm just wondering what does the ; mean.

```
    $4 < $in > $5
    if  diff $5 $out  >/dev/null 2>&1 ;  
    then
       echo "same!"
    else
       echo "different!"
    fi
```

(This is in Bourne Shell)

Comment: Seriously? All that and what you're asking is what `;` does in sh?

Comment: I'm also asking about the $5 part. lol. I'll try to make that into a question.

Comment: I want the output of "$4 < $in" to be compared with $out.

Comment: lol ok. How do I compare the output of $4 < $in" to $out   ? (I don't think I need $5.)

Comment: Will we regret it if we ask what `$1`, `$2` and `$3` represent?  What exactly are you trying to do?  Please explain at a high level. (For example, "I'm trying to compare the old and new versions of a C source file after compiling them to ensure they're both sound", except that only seems to require two arguments and not `$in` or `$out` too.)

Comment: $1, $2, $3 are used for something else not related to this. So, $in  input file to the C program $4. I want the new output of $4 < $in to be compared with the old output of $out.  (I already wrote something to compile the C program $4. It works fine.)

Comment: OK — confusion reigneth! A C file normally means a source file, not a program; that's just 'a program' or perhaps 'a C program'.  By the time it's an executable, it's more like machine code than C.

Answer (score 1):

The semi-colon is redundant, but marks the end of the `diff` command.  It could have been followed by another command, but isn't.

*[I've removed some comments based on a misunderstanding of what a 'C file' is.  In this context, it means a 'program written in C' rather than a C source file.]*

Comment: oh sorry, about the confusion.

Comment: I think I found my problem.